# Objective C: Opening A PDF File on iBooks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, ibooks, uidocumentinteraction

I am downloading a PDF file from an online server and save it to my the App's Sandbox then view it in iBooks.

The iBooks viewing is what i am struggling now.
I tried this code:

```
    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

    docController.delegate = self;

    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:savePDF.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [docController dismissMenuAnimated:YES];
```

Still gor no chance, It is running but the popover is being dismissed right away after it was presented. But when I deleted `[docController dismissMenuAnimated:YES];` it gives me an error saying `'-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'`

What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to hang on to the docController reference in an instance variable until it is done displaying.

Comment: @borrrden How will I able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `UIDocumentInteractionController` is being released right after being presented, due to the variable `docController` no longer being in scope.

To prevent that, you should create a `strong` property or an instance variable and store your `UIDocumentInteractionController` in there. That way, the `UIDocumentInteractionController` will stick around until you release the object controlling it, which should be long enough for the user to make a selection...

Comment: Technically, there is no garbage collection in iOS (ARC is a compiler feature, and behind the scenes it will use reference counting)

Comment: @borrrden You're right, I didn't bother to research that... Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything again and again but finally got the **[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible** error to go away and all is working by doing this:

> Go to your Project Build Phases --> then Compile Sources --> choose
>   the .m that you are having the issue with and double click the
>   Compiler Flag and add  **-fobjc-arc** then clean and build your app.

Again this wont work for everyone and may not be the right answer but it may also help a few others having the same issue I had.